# Como evitar la cache en firefox

Tags: html, laravel, firefox, programación-funcional

Buenas, queria saber que otra manera hay para evitar que firefox use el cache, para guardar nuestra pagina web, ahora utlizo los metas

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Pero no he logrado, evitar el cache, vale aclarar que estoy usando laravel 5.4 para el desarrollo de la web.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Te faltan unos cuántos métodos entre ellos `no-store` y `must-revalidate`. 
**ESTAS ETIQUETAS SOLO FUNCIONAN CON HTML 4.0 O SUPERIOR**